# Should my employer pay for my 2 weeks? Am i eligible for Unemployment

Tags: notice-period, quitting

I gave my two weeks notice on 09/12, my direct boss told me my last day would be 09/26 then I was called into the office on 09/16 and told it was my last day?? Within a few hours I was packed up and shipped to an exit interview. Should my employer pay for my 2 weeks bc of my managers comments to me? If not Am i eligible for Unemployment? I gave a start date to my new job of 09/27 based on my managers comments

Comment: The answer depends a lot on where you are located. Laws and unemployment insurance work differently in different countries/regions.

Comment: Personally I would call up the new company and ask if I could start earlier.

Comment: IANAL, but if they're paying you through 9/26, you're probably not eligible for unemployment.

Answer (score 13):

There are two possibilities here. One is that your company has decided for reasons of liability or other legal reasons, that they don't want you to work or come in to the office while you serve out your notice. This is quite common in cases where an employee has access to confidential information or is in a position to damage the company should they choose. In this case you will still be paid by the company until 26th, they just aren't requiring you to show up or do any work. Your access and security privileges have probably been revoked. (I originally wrote "you are still employed by the company until the 26th", but this may not be the case. Practically speaking it doesn't make a lot of difference.)

The second possibility is that you have been pre-emptively fired. That's pretty unlikely, and in any jurisdiction except the US is pretty much impossible, since they would have to give you at least 2 weeks notice.

If you were given any paperwork as part of your exit interview, you will probably find it states clearly which one it is, and what your actual last day of employment is. If it's the first case, you will get paid up until the 26th. If it's the second, they might still be paying you, and if not you might have legal redress. If you don't know, or didn't get any paperwork, it's important that you find out. You are eligible for unemployment only if you were fired, and even then you probably won't get it if you have a job to go to.

The first scenario is by far the most likely, but you should take steps to confirm that as soon as possible.

P.S. I totally agree with HLGEM. Phone the new company and tell them you are unexpectedly free, and ask if you can start earlier. You can do this whether or not the old company is going to pay you up to the 26th. Or, if time is more valuable to you than money, go down to your travel agent and see if there are any last minute bargains for travel.